# Getting the value of an attribute in an XML document using XSL

Tags: xslt, xpath, docbook-5

I'm trying to get the value of `iWantToGetThis.jpg` and put it into an `<img>` during my XSL transformation. This is how my xml is structures:

```
<article>
    <info>
        <mediaobject>
            <imageobject>
                <imagedata fileref='iWantToGetThis.jpg'>
```

Here's what I've come up with for the XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="user.header.content">
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:d='http://docbook.org/ns/docbook'>
        <img><xsl:attribute name="src">../icons/<xsl:value-of select='ancestor-or-self::d:article/info/mediaobject/imageobject/imagedata/@fileref' /></xsl:attribute></img>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</xsl:template>
```

The image is being added to the output, but the src attribute is set to "../icons/", so I'm assuming it's not finding the `fileref` attribute in the XML. This looks perfectly valid to me, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you can get anything back at all, because that does not look like a valid XSLT document (I would expect the error "Keyword xsl:stylesheet may not contain img.").

However, it may be you are just showing a fragment of the code. If this is the case, your  issue may be that you have only specified the namespace for the **article** element, when you really need to specify it for all elements in your xpath. Try this

```
<xsl:value-of 
   select="ancestor-or-self::d:article/d:info/d:mediaobject/d:imageobject/d:imagedata/@fileref"/>
```

Another possible problem may be because you are using the 'ancestor-or-self' xpath axis to find the attribute. This would only work if your current context was already on the **article** element, or one of its descendants.

As a side note, you can simplify the code by making use of Attribute Value Templates here

```
<img src="../icons/{ancestor-or-self::d:article/d:info/d:mediaobject/d:imageobject/d:imagedata/@fileref}" />
```

Comment: It was simply the lack of namespaces on children in the xpath expression.

Comment: This form of stylesheet is allowed when the full form would consist of just a single `<xsl:template match="/">` element. The stylesheet contains just the content of that template element. [Read about it here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#result-element-stylesheet).

Comment: The XSL I'm working with is a lot more fleshed out. I realized after posting this that it's not really a good XSL example...